# How to ask something in Android Auto and start voice recogniser for a reply?

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm developing an Android Auto enabled app and I'm asking a question like,

> Do you want to navigate?

In my case after ask the question, a voice recogniser must be enabled to get the answer `Yes` or `No`.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Android Speech Recognizer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class?

Comment: yes. I used it. But where do I implement it? What is the method that triggers after the end of the android auto device voice question?

Comment: You shall implement RecognitionListener http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html

Comment: I think you must get it on onEndOfSpeech() http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onEndOfSpeech()

Comment: I'm using CarEntender's unread conversation for this. How can I identify the end of this speech(Speech by auto device)? Not the voice recogniser.